# ASP.NET Changing Session-State Modes

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, iis-7.5, session-state

I'm attempting to share Session information between PHP and .NET on the same server. The sessions will always be created by the .NET site. From my research I've come to believe that the Session-State Mode "SQLServer" will be perfect for this, as the PHP can check session information directly in the database.

My problem is that the .NET application was developed years ago and uses the InProc Session-State. I have no experience working with ASP.NET. I have no way, that I know of, to test switching from InProc to SQLServer and the site must not go down!

1) Could using web.config to change the Session-State from InProc to SQLServer cause any problems for an old application?

2) Is there a way to test this, such as copying all the files to a test sub-domain?

3) If I bring the site down, is there any reason why I couldn't revert the old web.config and get everything back up.

4) Could using SQLServer instead of InProc cause any issues at all on the .NET side?

5) I also noticed in the IIS for the site there is a UI for changing the Session-States, is it better to use that or web.config (or both)?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can I ask what is the purpose of sharing session information between PHP and .NET website, do you want to achieve Single Sign On, or do are you trying to replace the .NET with the PHP?

Comment: Right now, Single Sign On. There are more micro PHP apps being created so it's not out of the realm of possibility that .NET may be replaced, just not anytime soon.

Comment: Are you using asp.net form authentication or integrated windows authentication?

Comment: It uses an asp.net form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to your above question

1. Yes there might be problems when changing to SQLServer due to .NET session doesn't just contain who is logged in etc, it also can keep user session information e.g. items selected and other objects.  (I don't know enough about your particular site, but when you move from InProc to SQL, you need to check any session object that will be stored in SQL is also serializable, otherwise it will fail) So a lot of testing.
2. you can test, by copy the website currently in the IIS to may be another machine with IIS and ASP.NET and make the appropriate change in the web.config, if you have production and test database, point it to test, I would NOT recommend to use any production database.
3. yes, make sure you back everything up including the database if you have any
4. yes see item (1)
5. you only need one, I would just modify the web.config only, back it up first.

Since you want to achieve single sign on, there are other options to explore,

- Security Token Service (but will need some amount code change on both .NET and PHP) see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/cc0a32b1-d5e0-4fdb-b369-a6215ca24b73/
- Integrated Windows Authentication (only works with IE on the intranet with windows logon) NOTE - this is not going to work in your case due to forms authentication

Comment: Thank you, I'm very concerned about causing any issues with the site. So, I'm going to try and figure out how to get the ASP login to add the userid and session number to a custom table for PHP to read from.

Comment: you welcome.  Custom table - I think that would be the simplest approach

Comment: Came back to say what I did, I have a link to the PHP app on the ASP site, when the user clicks it they are redirected to sessionphp.aspx where it puts the session information in the database. It then redirects to a php login page with post variables. The php checks the post data and IP address then automatically creates a session and finally redirects them to the main page of the PHP app. Not totally secure, but it works well and the user is redirected so fast the don't notice how clunky the whole process is :P